# Typo3 v7.6.39 finding orphan files

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, orphaned-objects

I have a Typo3 v7.6.39 website and I have a lot of files uploaded in different folders under user_upload. How can I see which files are orphan files (files that are not used or linked on my webpage)?

I already tried db_check under admin tools, but it finds only the files in one directory, not all of them. The orphaned files were uploaded through BE in Typo3.

TNX and BR!
Marco